# Ace Editor RequireJS Referencing ace/ext-language_tools Dependencies "ace/lib/oop" and "ace/lib/event_emitter"

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bower, ace-editor

I'm using RequireJS to load the ace editor. I'm not having any issues getting most of the editor and its dependencies loaded. But I'm specifically referencing ace/ext-language_tools, but it loads additional references "ace/lib/oop" and "ace/lib/event_emitter", but these files don't exist in the ace-build bower library. They only exist in the source code. I'm trying to use the built and minified version, but I can't seem to get these additional files referenced. What am I doing wrong? Is there some reason these files aren't being built with either the CDN version at https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ace/ or the ace-build bower library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In built version ace/lib/oop and ace/lib/event_emitter are declared in ace.js file

see the example below

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.3/ace.js></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.3/ext-language_tools.js></script>

<script>
  editor = ace.edit()
  document.body.appendChild(editor.container)
  editor.container.style.height = '100px'
  editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
  })
  editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript")
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, so I switched over to the src-min-noconflict version of the build, it found the oop and event_emitter dependencies, but now it can't find lib/lang. Where is that at?

Comment: all deps are in ace.js. There may be some other issue you are seeing but i can't know what it is without seeing the code. Please make a snippet similar to the one above demonstrating the error.

Comment: It was my mistake, I was referencing ace/lib/lang somewhere else, your answer was entirely correct. Thank you for your help.